# Regex solution to {First_name and First_name Last_name} pattern:

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text-parsing

This following, I presume, applies regex as used in Python.  If there's another way to do this outside of regex, I'm open to that.

I'm need to turn a string of this format:

```
'{First_name1} and {First_name2 Last_name}'

    (i.e. John and Mary Jones)
```

**to:**

```
'{First_name1 Last_name2}, {First_name2 Last_name2} 

    (i.e. John Jones, Mary Jones)
```

Being new to regex, this is one pattern that has stumped me. I assume that I'll have to find instances of the entire segment, capture the last name, and use .sub() to add a copy in the right place?

**EDIT :** While the solutions presented so far do answer the question, I thought I'd mention I found another situation that's being caught by the solutions so far.  That is the following:

`{First_name1 Last_name1, and First_name2, Last_name2}`

Apologies for not having seen (and thus, written in my original question) this pattern before.

So far, I've modified one of the answer to get this far:

`([^,]+)(?!\W,)( and [^ ]+ )([^ ]+)`

I thought I'd filter based on that comma in this last example. My thinking is that if the comma is present, then I want to move on to the next case. Does that make sense?

Comment: You'll need to define what a "first name" and a "last name" is.  You're assuming that each name is only one word, but that may not be the case.  What if you have Mary Ann Summers?  First name has two words.  What if you haven Eddie Van Halen?  Last name has two words.

Comment: @AndyLester - First_name and Last_name are, respectively, single words. There are, as you mention, cases of middle names, two-word first or last names (hyphenated, apostraphized, etc.), but for the sake of this situation, these are edge cases that I'm ok with the regex skipping.

Comment: Here's what I've come up with: 
`(?!\s)(\W[^\W,]+)(?!,)( and [^ ]+ )([^ ]+)`.  Not sure if it's hitting every case detailed above, but on the small dataset I'm looking at, it seems okay.

Comment: Stop writing code now. Step back and describe the strings you are trying to parse, preferably using a notation like BNF. Collect a list of the various strings to be parsed, and validate that your BNF matches them. THEN convert your BNF to a parser, regex, or whatever. Incremental stabbing/poking at an organically-evolving regex is the descent into regex hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @MonkeyZeus, this did the trick:

`(?!\s)(\W[^\W,]+)(?!,)( and [^ ]+ )([^ ]+)`

Answer (score 2):

If your data are always in this format then there is no need that I can see to do a regex, you can simply split the string and use indexing to construct the names you wants in the format you require:

```
a = 'John and Mary Jones'
a_split = a.split()
[(a_split[0], a_split[-1]), (a_split[-2], a_split[-1])]
```

results in

```
[('John', 'Jones'), ('Mary', 'Jones')]
```

Comment: Just to add, you can combine them by adding a `join` to your example: `[' '.join(a_split[0], a_split[-1]), ...]`. Results in `'John Jones'` instead of `('John', 'Jones')`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your exact input example is concerned then you can use:

```
([^ ]+)( and [^ ]+ )([^ ]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/HkMiWi/1